# Possible to style select element so style of selected option is shown when dropdown 'closed'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Given this simple html,

```
<select id="ddl">
    <option style="background:#0f0">a</option>       
    <option style="background:#f00;">b</option>   
    <option>c</option>
</select>
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/DxK47/)
You can see that each option has it's own background colour.

Unfortunately, when whatever option is selected (causing the dropdownlist to 'close'),  the background remains white (or whatever the page default is).

Is it possible to have the background of the selected item be displayed in the dropdownlist after the selection has been made (ideally without using javascript)

Comment: i found that issue in chrome and not in IE, just tried your fiddle and it was working normally in IE, can you give a try ?

Comment: do you want solutions without JS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, is possible

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("#ddl").on("change", function(){
        $("#ddl").css("background", $("#ddl option:selected").attr("style").replace("background:",""));
    });       
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SnakeEyes/DxK47/3/

and remove the `;` from second option

`<option style="background:#f00;">b</option>`

to

```
<option style="background:#f00">b</option>
```

**Other solution**: http://jsfiddle.net/SnakeEyes/DxK47/13/

Comment: Kinda nice, downside is would have to specify the background colour of every single option item, as the default is 'transparent'

Comment: @maxp: See **Other solution**

Comment: @SnakeEyes: Your "other solution" seems to work well, except no style is applied on page load (i.e., the select doesn't have a green background even though "a" is selected). This is easily remedied by running line three of your solution once *outside* the `on()` event.

Comment: Of course, you can set that. I wrote only for `onchange` event.

Comment: This version removes the need to set each option item's bg colour using jquery. Also initialises as per Cory's comment.   http://jsfiddle.net/b2PLY/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) library

> Chosen is a JavaScript plugin that makes long, unwieldy select boxes
>   much more user-friendly. It is currently available in both jQuery and
>   Prototype flavors.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not participating in contributions to this library.

Answer (score 1):

When CSS4 introduces the parent selector it may be possible, but for now there is no way to style a parent based on its children.  In the meantime, here is a simple JS solution:

```
$("#ddl").change(function () {
   $(this).css('background-color', $(this).find(":selected").css('background-color'));
});
```

**NOTE**: this requires *all* of the `<option>` to have a specified background color even if it's white.  That's pretty simple to do with JS too if you don't feel like it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done with a little bit of JavaScript. I made you a small example at JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DxK47/84/

I used jQuery here, I leave it to you as an exercise to do a similar trick with other js frameworks or even pure js if that's what you want.

```
$("#ddl").change(function(evt) {
  var select = evt.currentTarget;
  var item = select.item(select.selectedIndex);
  var style = $(item).attr("style");
  if (style) {
    $("#ddl").css({"background-color": style.substring(11)});
  } else {
    $("#ddl").css({"background-color": ""});
  }
});
```

Edit: I was too slow (and not a jQuery expert), look at above answers for more brief examples that do basically the same.

Answer (score -1):

This syntax will work in XHTML and does not work in IE6, but this is a non-javascript way, as you requested:

```
option[selected] { background: #f00; }
```

If you want to do this on-the-fly, then you would have to go with javascript, the way others have suggested....

Comment: This is not what the question was asking