# Hide option select item in woocommerce product type

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, woocommerce

I am planning to deliver a woocommerce shop to someone and I want to hide none essential options in order not to confuse non advance users. Particularly Product type.

In WooCommerce Product Editor, there is an option to select product type. I only want to show Simple and variable product.

Normally this could be done using css display:hide attributes but when I inspect woocommerce product option select, the options does not have id nor class selector.

Here is the code I saw on product options

```
<select id="product-type" name="product-type">
<optgroup label="Product Type"><option value="simple" selected="selected">Simple product</option>
<option value="grouped">Grouped product</option><option value="external">External/Affiliate product</option>
<option value="variable">Variable product</option></optgroup>
</select>
```

My question. Is there a way to hide grouped product and affiliate product type on that option select box in a way that it wont be affected during woocommerce or wp update?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use named selectors:

```
#product-type option[value="grouped"] {
    ... your css here ...
}
```

See this post: [CSS to select another Element based on a HTML Select Option Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452634/css-selector-for-select-option-value)

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks @cale_b

Answer (score 27):

You can filter `product_type_selector`

```
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'remove_product_types' );

function remove_product_types( $types ){
    unset( $types['grouped'] );
    unset( $types['external'] );

    return $types;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this. This code should work and it work best with woocommerce 3.4.4 and above.
Refrence:
https://gist.github.com/tanmay27vats/89f9d67db78c33a6ffa1d844235a5db1

```
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'remove_product_types' );

function remove_product_types( $types ){
    unset( $types['grouped'] );
    unset( $types['external'] );
    unset( $types['variable'] );

    return $types;
}
```