# Auto Add All Product Attributes When Creating a New Product in WooCommerce - Multisite Environment

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm setting up a WordPress multisite network with WooCommerce and trying to make it so all product attributes are automatically selected and added to a product when you start creating a product.

I tested the solution found here:
[Auto add all product attributes when adding a new product in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113840/auto-add-all-product-attributes-when-adding-a-new-product-in-woocommerce)

This solution worked perfectly when I tested it on a single site.

However, when I put this on the multisite network, it stopped working properly.

On the multisite network, when creating a new product, it is adding the attributes and selecting the checkboxes correctly, however, it is not adding the "Values" for each attribute.

Ideally, all the options available in the "Values" section would be automatically selected as well.

Again, this worked perfectly on the single site instance, but as soon as I copied it over to the multisite environment, it stopped working.

*Note: I made a couple other customizations to help simplify the user experience for the end user. These other customizations did not appear to interfere or cause conflict with my test on the single site. I copied over all the same customizations onto the multisite network. Since every customization is the same between the single site instance and the multisite network instance, I believe the main issue is there needs to be an alteration because of this being a multisite network. Here are references to the other customizations I made in case you'd like to review:*

- [Hiding extra WooCommerce fields](https://www.themelocation.com/how-to-remove-product-panel-tabs-admin-panel-in-woocommerce/)
- [Removing Product Types (simple, download, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746778/hide-option-select-item-in-woocommerce-product-type)

Here is the final code that I have inserted into my functions.php file for reference:

```
    ## --- HIDE PRODUCT TABS IN WOOCOMMERCE --- ##
function remove_linked_products($tabs){

   unset($tabs['general']);

                unset($tabs['inventory']);

                unset($tabs['shipping']);

                unset($tabs['linked_product']);

                unset($tabs['advanced']);

                return($tabs);

}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'remove_linked_products', 10, 1);


    ## --- HIDE PRODUCT TYPES IN WOOCOMMERCE --- ##
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'remove_product_types' );

function remove_product_types( $types ){
    unset( $types['grouped'] );
    unset( $types['external'] );
    unset( $types['simple'] );

    return $types;
}

    ## --- AUTOMATICALLY SELECT ALL ATTRIBUTES --- ##
add_action( 'save_post', 'auto_add_product_attributes', 50, 3 );
function auto_add_product_attributes( $post_id, $post, $update  ) {

    ## --- Checking --- ##

    if ( $post->post_type != 'product') return; // Only products

    // Exit if it's an autosave
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;

    // Exit if it's an update
    if( $update )
        return $post_id;

    // Exit if user is not allowed
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_product', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

    ## --- The Settings for your product attributes --- ##

    $visible   = ''; // can be: '' or '1'
    $variation = '1'; // can be: '' or '1'

    ## --- The code --- ##

    // Get all existing product attributes
    global $wpdb;
    $attributes = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies" );

    $position   = 0;  // Auto incremented position value starting at '0'
    $data       = array(); // initialising (empty array)

    // Loop through each exiting product attribute
    foreach( $attributes as $attribute ){
        // Get the correct taxonomy for product attributes
        $taxonomy = 'pa_'.$attribute->attribute_name;
        $attribute_id = $attribute->attribute_id;

        // Get all term Ids values for the current product attribute (array)
        $term_ids = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'fields' => 'ids'));

        // Get an empty instance of the WC_Product_Attribute object
        $product_attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();

        // Set the related data in the WC_Product_Attribute object
        $product_attribute->set_id( $attribute_id );
        $product_attribute->set_name( $taxonomy );
        $product_attribute->set_options( $term_ids );
        $product_attribute->set_position( $position );
        $product_attribute->set_visible( $visible );
        $product_attribute->set_variation( $variation );

        // Add the product WC_Product_Attribute object in the data array
        $data[$taxonomy] = $product_attribute;

        $position++; // Incrementing position
    }
    // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

    // Set the array of WC_Product_Attribute objects in the product
    $product->set_attributes( $data );

    $product->save(); // Save the product
}
```

I'm not a programmer and have made it this far by copying other people's customization instructions. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!