# Pure CSS way to show/hide content based on option select?

Tags: css

My question is similar to this one: [CSS to select another Element based on a HTML Select Option Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452634/css-selector-for-select-option-value)

Here's my HTML:

```
    <select id="select-card">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="card">**** **** **** 1982</>
    </select>
    <p>Or enter a new one...</p>
```

I want to hide the `<p>` when the user selects a card from the list, and show it when the user selects the empty option.

Is this possible in pure CSS, or do I need to use JavaScript?

Comment: You'll need JavaScript since there's no parent selector in CSS (yet).

Comment: _“My question is similar to this one”_ – in fact, it is so much alike, that I think this should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @CBroe well strictly speaking that question has no answer, which is why I linked to it and asked again...

Comment: That this is not possible because there is no parent selector in CSS _is_ the answer … and that still holds true.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NmdxC/6/ GL...

Answer (score 2):

Use the `required` attribute:

```
<select id="select-card" required>
```

And write rules for `valid` and `invalid` for the element, selecting the following p-element:

```
#select-card:invalid + p { display: block; }
#select-card:valid + p { display: none; }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhxd3x25/)

Comment: OK, nice “workaround” for this specific case. (Although not sure whether the implications of `required` are wanted here or not.)

Comment: @msfoster what if I want to change visibility of multiple `div`s and when I have more than 2 options?

Comment: @GauravPaliwal I suggest you create a question where you explain your problem in detail.