# html/css <select><option> show other html elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a css way to display `id="showMe"` when an option in select > option is selected?

```
<div class="option-container">
    <label class="select">
        <label for="mode">Mode</label>
        <select type="dropdown" id="ddraw-mode" class="ddraw-select" required>
            <option selected="selected" value="fullscreen">Fullscreen (default)</option>
            <option value="borderless">Borderless</option>
            <option value="windowed">Windowed</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</div>

    <p id="showMe">
        show me
    </p>
</div>

<style>
  #ddraw-select:invalid + #showMe { display: block; }
  #ddraw-select:valid + #showMe { display: none; }
</style>
```

Also I cannot use JavaScript.. if I could then It would be too easy.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please ***[do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=CSS+OR+javascript+show+when+select+site:stackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Why is the `p` not in a div?

Comment: The <p> is really arbitrary I'm just trying to scope "showMe" when select>option is selected

Comment: stackoverflow is trying to tell me this question is already answered but I don't understand css (personally) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612521/pure-css-way-to-show-hide-content-based-on-option-select
Could I do `ddraw-select + showMe`