# How to style select dropdown only when value is empty

Tags: html, css

Lets say I have markup like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>    
</select>
```

Now, I want the dropdown to display in gray ONLY when the value is empty i.e when it is showing "Select". When the user has selected one of the options, it should be black / default color.

(This is to be visually consistent with textboxes on my page that have gray placeholders).

I want to accomplish something like this:

```
select[value=""] {
    color: gray;
}
```

But it turns out that the select tag doesn't really have a value attribute.

Any way to accomplish this other than using JavaScript?

Comment: Good question.  I don't know of a way

Comment: Do you just want the text of the word "Select" to be gray? Or do you want the background of that item to be gray? OR do you want the background of the entire dropdown box to be gray?

Comment: Just the word select.

Comment: Do you mind using jquery

Comment: I dont exactly mind, i just want to checkout pure-css options before i use js. With js this is straightforward. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to find **(http://jsfiddle.net/Idered/LufkN/)** that might be the closest you'll come to achieving your desired effect without javascript. Hope it helps in some way.

Comment: @Frankenscarf that link is really close.. good search

Comment: Thanks @Frankenscarf! Though it doesn't directly answer my question, thats an elegant dropdown!

Comment: @Natarajan Shanker: Yea, that's why I didn't post it as an official "answer". Frankly it opens a whole new can of worms when it comes to form validation and getting the "selected value".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Style <select> element based on selected <option>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344583/style-select-element-based-on-selected-option)

Answer (score 9):

Styling options, will only style them as shown in the drop down list, not when the select is not in focus. I wanted the select to be italic when the blank option is shown, it can be achived like this (note the blank option must have `value=""` set):

```css
/* If the select does not have a valid value, ie the blank option is selected, we make it italic */
select:invalid {
    font-style: italic;
}

/* Now the child options inherit the italics style, so we reset that*/
select > option {
    font-style: normal;
}

/* Apply italics to the invalid options too when shown in the dropdown */
select option[value=""], select option:not([value]) {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<select required>
  <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>  
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Or using `onchange` attribute (works without `required` attribute):

```css
/* If the select does not have the attribute [data-empty="false"] */
select:not([data-empty="false"]) {
    font-style: italic;
}

/* Now the child options inherit the italics style, so we reset that*/
select > option {
    font-style: normal;
}

/* Apply italics to the invalid options too when shown in the dropdown */
select option[value=""], select option:not([value]) {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="this.dataset.empty = this.value == ''">
  <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>  
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me in chrome 103.0.5060.114 Mac.

Could you provide a fiddle/codepen showing it working?

Comment: @Timidfriendly the blank option must have `value=""`, added the code snippet above you can run.

Comment: Only works if the `select` element is set to `required`. If it's not required, a blank value won't be interpreted as invalid.

Comment: @user3250386, added another method using onchange.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the new `:has` pseudo-class.

This is a **CSS only solution** with a **[global support of 87.43%](https://caniuse.com/?search=has)** (**On June 2023 Firefox still does not support the** `:has` **pseudo-class**).

The code inside the snippet below will color the select in grey if the selected option has an empty value `<option value="">Select</option>` or `<option value>Select</option>` and it will color the select in black if the value of the selected option is not empty.

In any cases the options will always be black.

If you want the options to follow the select coloring, just set the default color of the option as the same one of the select:

```
select {
  color: grey;
}

select option {
  color: grey;
}
```

```css
select {
  color: grey;
}

select option {
  color: black;
}

select:has(option:checked:not([value])),
select:has(option:checked:not([value=""])) {
  color: black;
}

select:has(option:checked:not([value])) option,
select:has(option:checked:not([value=""])) option {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>    
</select>
```

You can read more about the `:has` pseudo-class on the [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) and check the support on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=has).

Answer (score 1):

You can use pseudo classes `:first-child`, `:nth-child(1)`, `:nth-of-type(1)`, if your empty option always will be on the first position. As I understand, option with empty value and text "Select" should be first, as default. In this case, we will be aware that.

Answer (score 1):

Sweet and Simple, Just add below CSS will resolve your issue. I hope it'll help you out.

```
select option[value=""] {
  color: red;
}
```

- Verified on Google Chrome: **Version 92.0.4515.107 (Official Build)
  (64-bit)**
- Verified on Firefow: **Version 90.0.2 (64-bit)**

```css
select option[value=""] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>    
</select>

<select>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="">Two</option>  
    <option value="3">Three</option>  
    <option value="">Four</option>  
</select>
```

Comment: Does not solve OP question. When your code shows "Select", it is not red, only when the drop down is shown.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, the OP selector solution is:

```
select:required:has(option[value=""]:checked) { ... }
```

Comment: Use the :required only if the select has that attribute, otherwise the CSS does not match.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="backGround" size="1" onChange="updateTextColour(this.value);"><!--changeColor(this.selected);"-->
            <option style="color:Gray">Select</option>
            <option style="color:Black">Value 1</option>
            <option style="color:Black">Value 2</option>
</option>
        </select></span></span></td>
```

Comment: That's JavaScript. OP specifically mentioned a solution that's not JavaScript.

Comment: Hmm thanks yeah thats kinda my last resort, i'm wondering if theres a way to do this without JS. I find it weird that select shouldn't have a value attribute when input does.

Comment: let me check this out!

Comment: @NatarajanShanker That's because for `select`, the `value` is specified in each `option`, and not the `select` itself.