# Change opacity for select element if option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have multiple select-elements like this:

```
<li>
    <select>
        <option>select something</option>
        <option value="1">something</option>
        <option value="2">anything</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <select>
        <option>select something</option>
        <option value="1">something</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <select>
        <option>select something</option>
        <option value="1">something</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

Now I need to change the opacity to 0.5 for every select element which has a selected option after the page has loaded. I'm not quite sure if this can be done by pure CSS, so I tried to do that with JQuery:

```
$('select').each(function(select) {
    $('select option').each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':selected')) {
            select.css({ opacity: 0.5 });
        }
    });
});
```

But this is not correct as it doesn't work.

Comment: `<li>` is not closed

Comment: Do you want to `disable` it or just change the opacity?

Comment: Just change opacity, because I want to set the opacity back to 1 on a mouseover-event

Comment: this might work for you

Comment: a `select` element with options always has one option selected... what exactly are you trying to do

Comment: @billynoah I'm thinking of a selected option except the default one (=first option without value)

Comment: none of the options in your question have a value.  please update your question and respective code to illustrate exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @billynoah I have updated the post. If 'select something' is selected the opacity should be 1. If anything else is selected it should be 0.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Style <select> element based on selected <option>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344583/style-select-element-based-on-selected-option)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you assign an empty value to your default option.  Then simply bind a `change` event to your `select` elements, trigger it once on page load (in case the selected value is not default) and use CSS for your hover opacity.

```js
 $('select').on('change', function() {
   if (this.value) {
     $(this).css('opacity', '0.5');
   } else {
     $(this).css('opacity', '1');
   }
 }).change();
```

```css
select:hover {
  opacity: 1!important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <select>
      <option value="">select something</option>
      <option value="1">something</option>
      <option value="2">anything</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li>
    <select>
      <option value="">select something</option>
      <option value="1" selected="selected">something</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li>
    <select>
      <option value="">select something</option>
      <option value="1">something</option>
    </select>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need use `change` event instead of two `.each`

```js
function isNotEmpty(element) {
  return ($('option:selected', element).attr('value') || '').length;
}

$('select').on('change mouseout',function () {
  $(this).css({ opacity: isNotEmpty(this) ? 0.5 : 1 });
}).on('mouseover', function () {
  $(this).css({ opacity: 1 })
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <select>
      <option>select something</option>
      <option value="1">something</option>
      <option value="2">anything</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li>
    <select>
      <option>select something</option>
      <option value="1">something</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li>
    <select>
      <option>select something</option>
      <option value="1">something</option>
    </select>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').each(function(select) {
    $('select option').each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':selected')) {
            $(this).parent.css('opacity', '0.5');
        }
    });
});
```