# Select-option-checked-value -- Is it possible with CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I have a basic `<select>` box with two `<option>`s.  I want to know if I can give a `style` to the `<select>` box based on a selected `<option>` (which has no ID, only a value), in pure CSS.  The CSS that I have here only works for the bottom style, regardless of what option is chosen on page load.

Here is what I have:

```css
#foo,
option[value="2"]:checked {
  border: 2px solid #FF9999;
}
#foo,
option[value="1"]:checked {
  border: 2px solid #2fa154;
}
```

```html
<select id="foo">
  <option value="1">Bar 1</option>
  <option value="2">Bar 2</option>
</select>
```

Is what I am asking possible with pure CSS without the use of jQuery etc.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Style <select> element based on selected <option>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344583/style-select-element-based-on-selected-option)

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no way to do this with css3 only.

Comment: Please either add info from that question directly into your answer, or refrain from posting this as an answer. Currently it is a link only answer and does not provide any detail how to solve the question.

Comment: @gitsitgo you should not of downvoted, inafalcao did answer the question correctly.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith you should not assume I was the downvoter, because I didn't. I was only asking him to describe the alternative solution he was proposing.

Comment: @gitsitgo there is no alternative, OP asked for css only, no jquery.

Comment: @gitsitgo Question: "Is what I am asking possible with pure CSS without the use of jQuery etc.?"
Answer: "Currently, there is no way to do this with css3 only."
NEXT!