# How do i change the color of <h:selectOneMenu> Dropdown menu on selecting an entry in JSF?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsf, drop-down-menu

This is a sample code:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
 xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/DataTable.js"></script>
<h:body>
<h:selectOneMenu value="test1"
styleClass="combobox" id="profileID"> 
<f:selectItem itemLabel="--Select--" itemValue="--Select--"/>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Yes"/>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="No"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
</h:body>
</ui:composition>
```

Now when i select an option, i want the minimized dropdown menu rectangle to change it's background color, highlighting the selected option.If i choose 'Yes', the rectangle should turn 'Green', if i select 'No', the rectangle should turn 'Red'. How can this be implemented?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Style <select> element based on selected <option>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344583/style-select-element-based-on-selected-option)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep `data-*` attribute to store `color` value for selected option.

```js
document.getElementById('cars').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var bgColor = this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].dataset.color;
  this.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
  [].forEach.call(this.options, function(option) {
    option.style.backgroundColor = 'white'; //As options will inherit backgroundColor from parent `select`, do set it as `#fff` after every onchange
  });
  this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].style.backgroundColor = bgColor; //If you want selected color of `data-color`
});
```

```html
<select id="cars">
  <option data-color="green" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option data-color="green" value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option data-color="pink" value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option data-color="blue" value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I will mind answering this as it is not part of the question! Do edit your question and do provide parsed(browser readable) HTML.

Comment: Can you help out now @RayonDabre ?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```js
$('select').change(function(){
  if (this.value == 'volvo') {
    $(this).css('background','lime');
  }
  if (this.value == 'saab') {
    $(this).css('background','red');
  }
  if (this.value == 'opel') {
    $(this).css('background','blue');
  }
  if (this.value == 'audi') {
    $(this).css('background','yellow');
  }
});
```

```css
option {
  background: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `option` should not have any color I guess

Comment: `$(this)` refers to the `select`

Comment: When did I say it does not! ;(

Comment: the options dont get any color

Comment: Once `.css` is set, options inherit `background-color` from parent `select`.. Open select again and you will find it..

Comment: This works, but the color of the entire list gets changed when i select an option.

Comment: Now, if i wish to implement the same in jsf, using <h:selectOneMenu>, what all changes do i need to make? : `<h:selectOneMenu value="#{test.value}" styleClass="combobox" id="profileID"> 
<f:selectItem itemLabel="--Select--" itemValue="--Select--"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>`

Answer (score 0):

Do some jQuery and get the required behaviour.

```
$("body").on('change', 'select', function(){
            var val = $(this).val();
            if(val == 'volvo'){
                $(this).css("background-color", 'red');
            }
            if(val == 'saab'){
                $(this).css("background-color", 'green');
            }
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `option:checked` to highlight the selected option.

> the `:checked` pseudo-class initially applies to such elements that have
>   the HTML4 selected and checked attributes

**Source**: [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked)

```css
option:checked {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is select drop down not checkbox.

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya : `option:checked ` works even for drop down. Check the snippet above.

Comment: @Check the snippet

Comment: Still not working your demo..check robert code...it is working