# Multiple Select CSS Conditional Formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been looking for a way to style select boxes based on their selected option. The data is coming in from Django so there are populated fields on load.

I've been using this javascript/jQuery solution with some success.

[Style <select> element based on selected <option>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344583/style-select-element-based-on-selected-option)

The basic idea is that the selected option value is moved to a class in the select box so you can style off that class.

What I've done here is duplicate the code into two sections. Once to run on load and another to run on change.

```
$('select').attr('class', '').addClass($('select').children(':selected').val());

$('select').on('change', function(ev) {
  $(this).attr('class', '').addClass($(this).children(':selected').val());
});
```

This doesn't seem to work for multiple select boxes on load.

What happens is the on load code finds the first select box and then adds the class to all select boxes on the page, so basically it doesn't iterate over all select boxes and run one by one.

The second bit runs fine based on changing the select value.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9sx6fos7/

As you can see both boxes take the class of the first on load.

Thank you!

Comment: Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sx6fos7/1/).

Comment: That does the job. Thanks!