# change color of selected option using css attribute selector?

Tags: html, css, angular

I know how to achive that by writing a bit of code in typescript when (change) accures but I'm wondering what is the reason why this css code not working:

```
select[value="green"]{
  color:green;
}
select[value="red"]{
  color:red;
}
```

and the html example:

```
     <select class="custom-select">
        <option selected value="green" >my green option</option>
        <option value="red" >my red option</option>
     </select>
```

note: I don't mean color of text in dropdown menu itself but the color of text in select-space

Answer (score 3):

Because you should use `option` element for CSS, not `select` (it's parent element):

```css
option[value="green"]{
  color:green;
}
option[value="red"]{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<select class="custom-select">
  <option selected value="green" >my green option</option>
  <option value="red" >my red option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I guess I was unclear - I don't mean changing color of text in a drop down window I mean  changing color of text in select-window depending on option selected- if U understan what I mean hehe:)

Comment: @pb4now, ok, I understand now. I'm searching for solution, but as I know, it's not possible via pure HTML/CSS

Comment: ok, strangely enough there is a 'value' attribute of <select> that changes with changing of option - but it exist under 'target' so I thought that maybe I should put something like that in css [target.value="green"] put that is not alowed syntax in css :s P.s if U put value="green" programaticly in select-tag then that css code works:S

Comment: @pb4now, looks like my suggestions were right and it's not possible. For example, here is an answer to similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16345225/6053654. I also played around with some CSS trick such as `:has()`, `:parent`, `!` and so on, but with no luck. Sorry (

Comment: @pb4now, I tried the way with `value`, but yes, as you said, it doesn't work, works only with static value attribute, declared in HTML. `select` is a little more complex, than it looks