# How to apply italics on first option tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to apply half of text in non-italics and the other half in italics.
I need to do something like this:
[image]

I have tried the code below but nothing seems to be working... is anyone capable of solving this?

```css
#mySelect *.firstOption i {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option class="firstOption">not-italic <i>italic</i></option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Actually not possible, Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select

Comment: @JagjeetSingh i have seen that but it is post from 2011, surely there is someway now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style the option of a html "select"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to style the contents of the select based on the selected option, you can't do that with just CSS.

Here's a duplicate question about that:

- [Style <select> element based on selected <option>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344583/style-select-element-based-on-selected-option)

If you're asking about the placeholder text, then that's different again. You might need to post a snippet that includes how placeholder text is set and/or target platforms.

If you just want to style the first option in the dropdown list, then you can do that with just css by either:

1. Remove the asterisk (`*`), and the `i` selector from your code, and it will work. (I've removed the explicit `<i>` tags, as I assumed that's not what you want).

```css
#mySelect .firstOption {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option class="firstOption">alpha</option>
  <option>beta</option>
  <option>gamma</option>
</select>
```

2. You can also achieve this using the [`:first-child` selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) on the option element:

```css
option:first-child{
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>alpha</option>
  <option>beta</option>
  <option>gamma</option>
</select>
```

Comment: in your dropdown you have two "alphas". You have made the second alpha in italics. i also need the first alpha in italics. i hope that makes sense

Comment: Ah, so you want the selected option to appear in italics in the select box itself as well as the in the dropdown list, right?

Comment: yes @Ergwun, that is what i need. I need half of text to be in non-italics and other half in italics as well. sample: _alpha_ omega

Comment: Ok. Not sure about that, sorry. You might want to checkout out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder