# Pure CSS styling of <select> element but only when non-default option is selected

Tags: css, css-selectors, html-select, pseudo-class, noscript

Is it possible to conditionally style the following [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) element

```
<select>
  <option>one</option>
  <option selected>default</option>
  <option>two</option>
</select>
```

whenever the non-default options are selected, using pure CSS (no javascript)?

If there is a way, I would expect it to use some combination of [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes), something along the lines of

```
select:some-pseudo-class { border: 1px; }
```

but probably more complicated. I already looked through the [list of pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes#Index_of_standard_pseudo-classes) and it seems this isn't possible, but I want to confirm this with the wisdom of the crowds before giving up completely. I have also done some research on this site and came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344583/style-select-element-based-on-selected-option) from 2013 which is asking a more general question, where the (possibly outdated) answer is "no". I don't believe my question is an exact duplicate of this question, because I am asking if a special case is possible and I am looking for an answer that is up-to-date as of February 2020.

Comment: FYI parent selector is not possible with css. You need to use javascript or jquery

Answer (score -1):

You can try with the pseudo-class `option:checked {border: 1px;}`

Comment: Wouldn't that style the selected option element only? I am trying to style the select element (i.e. the parent)