# Is there a pure CSS way to style a select element differently when an option has been selected?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to achieve something with pure CSS that I am not sure is possible after some searching. I need to have a select element that is styled different once an option has been selected. The style is not reliant upon any particular option, just an option. Here is my dropdown:

```
<div>
    <select id="select_element" name="select_name">
        <option hidden disabled selected value=""></option>
        <option value="option">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label for="select_element">Question for select?</label>
</div>
```

How can I properly target the select element once an option has been selected? I am trying to apply different styles for the select in its base state and once an option has been selected. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344583/style-select-element-based-on-selected-option and scroll down for an answer with a tiny bit of js ('hold my beer').

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Style <select> element based on selected <option>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344583/style-select-element-based-on-selected-option)

Comment: The title of the linked question is "Style <select> element based on selected <option>
" so presumably it is a dupe (whether it has an answer to your question is another matter, but the q itself is a dupe).

Comment: Aside from that it is a great question.  Just has been asked before.

Comment: selector level 4 specification define has() but it could be that is not already implemented https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational

Answer (score 1):

You can't, you need to use js...