# Css set background-color of the selected option to the background of select-tag

Tags: html, css

The different options of the html select form field show the correct 'colors' of my options as the background-color.

But when one option is selected and thus the select element is shown 'collapsed' it shows a default white background.

What is a clean way to update the background of the select box to the one of the option ?

```html
<select>
  <option style="background-color: #CDBA88">RAL:1000</option>                
  <option style="background-color: #D0B084">RAL:1001</option>                
  <option style="background-color: #D2AA6D">RAL:1002</option>                
  <option style="background-color: #F9A800">RAL:1003</option>                
  <option style="background-color: #E49E00">RAL:1004</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: I think you need to use JS or something like that.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58132836/15690728) might help you

Comment: What system are you using as on my Safari IOS 15 the options do not have a background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Javascript as well. So, in a nutshell, on `onchange` event, you have to assign a function that sets background color to `<select>` component.

Here is a working snippet of what I mean:

```js
var selectBox = document.getElementById('select-box');

function applyBackgroundColor() {

  // Check if DOM element exists, otherwise return
  if (!selectBox) {
    return;
  }

  selectBox.style.backgroundColor = selectBox.value;
}

selectBox.onchange = applyBackgroundColor;
```

```html
<select id="select-box">
  <option value="#cdba88" style="background-color: #cdba88">RAL:1000</option>
  <option value="#d0b084" style="background-color: #d0b084">RAL:1001</option>
  <option value="#d2aa6d" style="background-color: #d2aa6d">RAL:1002</option>
  <option value="#f9a800" style="background-color: #f9a800">RAL:1003</option>
  <option value="#e49e00" style="background-color: #e49e00">RAL:1004</option>
</select>
```