# How do you enable :has() selector on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-selectors, settings

When I check the `:has()` CSS selector on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=has), it tells me that since Firefox103 it has been

> Supported in Firefox behind the layout.css.has-selector.enabled
> flag.

So how do I find this flag and enable it?

Comment: Any knows why is this behavior in since Firefox 103?

Comment: Please note that even in Chrome, this `:has(...)` selector is not really stable if your css query is dynamic and complicated. For example, `:has(:hover div>a[href])`. The browser don't know the triggering of this `:hover` css query so that it cannot really perform well.

Comment: AS of Firefox 115 this CSS rule works, however it needs sometimes to be placed on the parent of the parent; eg: `.menu a:has(img){...}` does NOT work but  `.menu:has(a > img) { ... }` DOES work.

Comment: @ChesterFung That might be because you're using it wrong. I don't even know what you're trying to achieve. So of course it doesn't work.

Comment: @s123 imagine you have a big container (call it `div.bc`), a smaller container (call it `div.sc`), and the `a[href]` element.  You want to make a css such that, when cursor moves into the `div.sc` that contains `a[href]`, the big container will change its background color. `div.bc:has(div.sc:hover a[href]){background:red}`. However in reality, Chrome will become very slow to handle this selector, and Firefox will become buggy for the detection. So just avoid using `:has` and use JavaScript.

Comment: @s123 see demo https://stackoverflow.com/a/77160163/6764107

Comment: @ChesterFung That's also not a good example. I haven't tried it yet but I doubt JavaScript would be much faster.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Go to the Firefox `about:config` page, then search and toggle `layout.css.has-selector.enabled`.

[image]

Comment: As of November 29, 2022, this is an outdated spec and it doesn't seem to work very well

Comment: According to [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/?search=has) it's supposed to be supported after enabling it, for Firefox 103+ (current max 109), I made a [quick test](https://i.imgur.com/yXGSImC_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand) (v107.0.1) and it seems to work

Comment: Please note that even in Chrome, this `:has(...)` selector is not really stable if your css query is dynamic and complicated. For example, `:has(:hover div>a[href])`. The browser don't know the triggering of this `:hover` css query so that it cannot really perform well.

Comment: The flag doesn’t seem to work in 108.0.2, does it? A simple demo [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73798163/2083613) works in Chrome, bot not in Firefox.

Comment: @dakab Still does not work in 109.0.1.

Comment: As of Firefox 110 the "has" selector doesn't seem to work even with the flag layout.css.has-selector.enabled

Comment: Same for me, this flag seems to be not working in 109.0.1 +

Comment: Even worse...

the javascript check `CSS.supports ("selector(:has(:focus))"))` returns TRUE, if the value in about:config is enabled, even if it is not working in firefox 1.109+. 

Than means we can no longer trust on the `CSS.supports()` method :(

Comment: Just upgraded to v111.  Still not working.  Damned frustrating!

Comment: There is an open bugzilla bug for this that the devs have said they intend to address in the first half of '23.  More: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=418039#c62

Comment: @wesbos Outdated spec? Says who?

Comment: The flag works. It's just that there are still some bugs, which is why it's currently experimental.

Comment: On their [Discourse page](https://connect.mozilla.org/t5/ideas/when-is-has-css-selector-going-to-be-fully-implemented-in/idc-p/27010/highlight/true#M19088), Honza (Mozilla employee) said it was planned to release in '23…

Comment: do Firefox expect end users to enable this? why is it disabled by default?

Answer (score 3):

On latest version of Firefox version 121, they have implemented the `:has()`.
Kindly refer the following link for the updates,
https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/121.0beta/releasenotes/