# Pseudoselector :has not work on firefox but works on chrome and Opera

Tags: css

```css
.main:has(article:nth-child(n + 2)) .role * {
font-size:55px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <article><div class="role"><span>Ruolo1</span> </div> contenuto1 </article> 
   <article><div class="role"><span>Ruolo2 </span> </div> contenuto2 </article> 
  <article><div class="role"><span>Ruolo3 </span> </div> contenuto3 </article> 
  <article><div class="role"><span>Ruolo4 </span> </div> contenuto4 </article> 

</div>
```

Why the CSS not working on firefox ?

The font size will be 55px for all elements except the first

Comment: Because `has()` has no [support on firefox](https://caniuse.com/?search=has())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this moment (April 2023) Firefox does not support :has() by default.

From the support table in MDN:
[image]

So you can test it in FF by setting the flag but if you have significant number of users on FF you may want to implement a workaround.

This snippet applies the font-size to all the articles unless there is only one article (i.e. unless the article is both the first and the last child).

```css
/*.main:has(article:nth-child(n + 2)) .role * {
font-size:55px;  
}*/

.main article:not(:first-child:last-child) .role * {
  font-size: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <article>
    <div class="role"><span>Ruolo1</span> </div> contenuto1 </article>
  <article>
    <div class="role"><span>Ruolo2 </span> </div> contenuto2 </article>
  <article>
    <div class="role"><span>Ruolo3 </span> </div> contenuto3 </article>
  <article>
    <div class="role"><span>Ruolo4 </span> </div> contenuto4 </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) that :has() has no support on firefox, it is supported by nearly all the other browsers.
There are some work arounds like this one:
[How do you enable :has() selector on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73936048/how-do-you-enable-has-selector-on-firefox). However, it is a compatibility issue and it never works as well as in other browsers.