# What is the syntax for JavaScript’s CSS supports method?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I am testing out the new `:has()` pseudo class. So far, only Firefox hasn’t enabled it by default.

I read in a comment on [How do you enable :has() selector on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73936048/how-do-you-enable-has-selector-on-firefox) about the following test:

```js
CSS.supports("selector(:has(:focus))"));
```

It returns `true` when I’ve enabled the setting on Firefox, and `false` otherwise, which is expected.

The thing is what does the `selector(:has(:focus))` actually mean? Obviously it’s testing for the `:has()` pseudoclass, but what’s with the `selector()` and the `(:focus)` parts. If I try to simplify it, the test doesn’t work — at least it returns a `false`.

I can’t find any detailed document on the `CSS.supports()` method which discusses it.

Comment: a word of warning - `:has` is broken in firefox, the results when enabled are inconsistent at best

Comment: @JaromandaX I read that in the referenced comments as well as on the bug reports. However, I see that it’s working on 114.0.2 on macOS, and that all of the comments are a few months old, so it may be on the mend.

Comment: It broke in 115!!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports_static

Comment: @JaromandaX I’ve just tested in 115.0.2 and both the selector and the test appear to work.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think I understand.

- `selector()` tests whether the syntax `:has(:focus)` is acceptable.
- `has(:focus)` is a dummy test. `:has()` won’t work because you can’t have an empty value, so it has to be `:has( something )`. The commenter use `:has(:focus)` but could just as well have used `:has(p)` or `:has(gorilla)` or `:has(…)`.

So, in English, the test is whether CSS supports the syntax `:has(anything)`.

Comment: [MDN @supports selector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports#selector_experimental)