How do I style a form select field, depending on selection with css or jquery?
I want to style the text color in the select field as gray (#b8b8b8), and when a selection (either Yes or NO) is made, the select field text should be styled as white (#fff).
<form>
  <select>
    <option selected disabled>please select</option>
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
  </select>
</form>

I tried all jquery solutions I could find on Stackoverflow, but none of those solutions apply to my needs. I tried using togglefields, but that styles ALL the text in the options, not the select field.
EDIT:
This is the last solution I tried:


function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myform").reset();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#selection").change(toggleFields);
});

function toggleFields() {
  if ($("#selection").val() == "none") {
    $("#selection").css("color", "blue");
  } else {
    $("#selection").css("color", "red");
  }
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
  <select id="selection">
    <option value="none" selected disabled>please select</option>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
  </select>
</form>



As you can see, it styles the "yes" and "no" options as red, but it doesn't style the "please select" option as blue. I also tried to target the disabled option directly with css, but that only changed the dropdown <option> styling when the list is open (dropped down), not the styling when the dropdown is initially closed upon loading of the page.

Your code is working. just compare with correct value $("#selection").val() == "yes": https://jsfiddle.net/frojts9w/

FYI the value for disabled options is null

**Solution **


<style>
    select {
      color: #b8b8b8;
      background-color: #333; /* Optional: Set a background color for better contrast */
    }
    select.valid {
      color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <select id="mySelect">
      <option selected disabled>please select</option>
      <option>Yes</option>
      <option>No</option>
    </select>
  </form>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val() !== 'please select') {
          $(this).addClass('valid');
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass('valid');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>




Thank you, Muhammad. Your solution works perfect!
NOTE: I had to remove 'please select' form the value and leave the field empty, otherwise the form will submit without any selection being made.
Solutions here don't work:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344583/style-select-element-based-on-selected-option
